# Presenting ViewController over another modalView

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have presented a `modalView(B)` on another `modalView(A)` which is presented on a navigation controller.

The problem is that the `dealloc` method of `modalView(A)` is never called, and somewhere the app crashes while fetching from `NSUserDefaults`.

I could not figure out what exactly is the problem?

EDIT :-

Code

```
ViewControllerA * aViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: aViewController];
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{}];
[aViewController release];
[navController release];
```

modalView(B)

```
ViewControllerB *bViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController: bViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];  
[bViewController release];
```

Comment: when you post a new controller modally the current controller is not dismissed, at least you did manually

Comment: ViewControllerA * aViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: aViewController];
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{}];[aViewController release];[navController release];

Comment: ViewControllerB *bViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];[self presentViewController: bViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];[bViewController release];

Comment: are you calling `dismissViewController` somewhere? furthermore, post the exact error message you get and the code where the debugger stops.

Comment: Where is NSUserDefaults which caused crash ?

Comment: + (NSString *)retriveFromUserDeaultsStringForkey:(NSString*)key {
    NSString *value = nil;
        value= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:key];  Error: Exe bad access
    if (value == nil || value == NULL) {
        value = @"";
    }
    return value ;
}